# What i'm doing wrong?

Tags: selenium

I'm practicing in selenium, not familiar jet neither with Java or Selenium but i'm trying so, i have written the below code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\Programming\\Selenium\\tools\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.ultimateqa.com/simple-html-elements-for-automation/");



Select dropDown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='et_pb_blurb_description']//select")));

int counter = dropDown.getOptions().size();

    for (int i=0; i<counter; i++){
    String expectedNames [] = {"Volvo","Saab","Opel","Audi"};

    WebElement items = dropDown.getOptions().get(i);
    String actualNames = items.getText();


    boolean isDisplay = dropDown.getOptions().get(i).isDisplayed();

    if (isDisplay){
        Assert.assertEquals(actualNames, expectedNames[0]);
        System.out.println("Item1 Asserted Succesfuly");
    }
    if (isDisplay){
        Assert.assertEquals(actualNames,expectedNames[1]);
        System.out.println("Item2 Asserted Succesfuly");
    }
    if (isDisplay){
        Assert.assertEquals(actualNames,expectedNames[2]);
        System.out.println("Item3 Asserted Succesfuly");
    }
    if (isDisplay){
        Assert.assertEquals(actualNames,expectedNames[3]);
        System.out.println("Item4 Asserted Succesfuly");
    }
}
```

I'm expecting:
Item1 Asserted Succesfuly
Item2 Asserted Succesfuly
Item3 Asserted Succesfuly
Item4 Asserted Succesfuly

But i get an assertion error expected [Saab] but found [Volvo], it does not go to read the elements of the expected names in the list for some reason

Comment: You never change the pulldown selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, it seems like your Selenium code is looking good.

The issue actually lies in the logic of your conditional statements:

```
if (isDisplay){
    Assert.assertEquals(actualNames, expectedNames[0]);
    System.out.println("Item1 Asserted Succesfuly");
}
if (isDisplay){
    Assert.assertEquals(actualNames,expectedNames[1]);
    System.out.println("Item2 Asserted Succesfuly");
}
if (isDisplay){
    Assert.assertEquals(actualNames,expectedNames[2]);
    System.out.println("Item3 Asserted Succesfuly");
}
if (isDisplay){
    Assert.assertEquals(actualNames,expectedNames[3]);
    System.out.println("Item4 Asserted Succesfuly");
}
```

In each iteration of the loop, your code goes into all 4 conditional statements (because `isDisplay=true`. The error occurs because you are then asserting if `actualNames` equals to `expectedNames[0], expectedNames[1], expectedNames[2], expectedNames[3]`.

To fix, you just need 1 `if` statement which utilizes the `i` counter to iterate through both the list and array, so that the corresponding item in both collections are the ones being matched against.

```
if (isDisplay){
    Assert.assertEquals(actualNames, expectedNames[i]);
    System.out.println("Item"+ i + " Asserted Succesfuly");
}
```

**A Slight Off-Track**

With that out of the way, I'm going to go a bit off-topic and say that for a drop-down list, there is usually a `value` attribute for each element in the list. For example:

```
<option value=volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value=saab">Saab</option>
```

A good practice would be to instead use this `value` attribute instead of the visible text, which you have done. The `isDisplayed()` method MIGHT return `false`, depending on the implementation of the dropdown element, especially if it isn't the default value of the dropdown list. The `value=volvo` attribute will always be available for you to use to select the element, as long as it appears in the DOM.

To do that, it's simple:

```
String expectedNames [] = {"volvo","saab","opel","audi"};
for (int=0; i<count; i++){
    WebElement item = dropDown.getOptions().get(i);
    String attrValue = item.getAttribute("value");

    Assert.assertEquals(attrValue, expectedNames[i]);
    System.out.println("Item " + i " asserted successfully.");
}
```

This will come in handy for you when you actually intend to click to select another option. Selenium may throw a `NoSuchElementException` error otherwise.

Comment: It was a very good explanation thank you very much for the help, i was able to clear some things. Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 1):

@Proko Notice that after your for loop first iteration it asserts first if condition but not subsequent because at next iteration Saas(2nd element in array) will come and same will fetched from `getOptions()` method so you don't need 4 if conditions, 1 is suffice to assert all values, remove all if condition except first and add i as index element for array. code for your reference.

```
if (isDisplay){
        Assert.assertEquals(actualNames, expectedNames[i]);
        System.out.println("Item1 Asserted Succesfuly");
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct, every time that I was looping, it took 4 items in every if, so after I returned only the (i) the result was correct. Thank you very much for the answer, I appreciated